# How to get the data via ajax in servlet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, servlets

I would like to send some data on the page to servlet

so I have written following jquery to do this

I use all data to build a json string, and directly send it to servlet

but I don't know how to get the whole data from the ajax in servlet

```
$("#save").click
(
    function()
    {
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url:'/WebApplication1/Controller',
                data:'{"name":"abc","address":"cde"}',
                type:'post',
                cache:false,
                success:function(data){alert(data);},
                error:function(){alert('error');}
            }
        );
    }
);
```

if see the the Form Data segment of request headers from chrome

you will see the whole json string is the key.

```
Request URL:http://192.168.0.13/WebApplication1/Controller
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:Big5,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:zh-TW,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:112
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:192.168.0.13
Origin:http://192.168.0.13
Referer:http://192.168.0.13/system_admin/building.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.910.0 Safari/535.7
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview URL encoded
{"name":"abc","address":"cde"}:
Response Headersview source
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Language:en
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Wed, 15 Feb 2012 12:37:24 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:accept-language,accept-charset
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look here,

```
data:'{"name":"abc","address":"cde"}',
```

Your `data` attribtue is wrong. It should not be a string, but a real JSON object. Remove those singlequotes.

```
data:{"name":"abc","address":"cde"},
```

This way it's available in the servlet the usual way

```
String name = request.getParameter("name"); // abc
String address = request.getParameter("address"); // cde
```

If it still doesn't work, head to [How should I use servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-should-i-use-servlets-and-ajax) for complete kickoff examples, just in order to exclude that your actual problem is caused elsewhere.

#### See also:

- [`jQuery.ajax()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

you can send data by ajax without any form, you can do it via GET or POST, but you have to invoke in some way the function that does the ajax petition (http request).

For example you can call your function from a link, this way:

the html:

```
<a href="" onClick="javascript: yourAjaxCallFunction(parameters)" >Link Text</a>
```

the javascript:

```
function yourAjaxCallFunction(parameters) 
{
  //this function sends the request via jquery ($().ajax) 
  sendHttpRequest(parameters);

  //this one handles the response (process data)
  processResult();
}
```

this link is maybe what you're looking for
[ajax function in jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)