# JQuery $.ajax() post - data in a java servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hashmap

I want to send data to a java servlet for processing.  The data will have a variable length and be in key/value pairs:

```
{ A1984 : 1, A9873 : 5, A1674 : 2, A8724 : 1, A3574 : 3, A1165 : 5 }
```

The data doesn't need to be formated this way, it is just how I have it now.

```
var saveData = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "someaction.do?action=saveData",
      data: myDataVar.toString(),
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(resultData){
          alert("Save Complete");
      }
});
saveData.error(function() { alert("Something went wrong"); });
```

The `$.ajax()` function works fine as I do get an alert for "Save Complete". My dilemna is on the servlet.  How do I retrieve the data?  I tried to use a HashMap like this...

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
hm.putAll(request.getParameterMap());
```

...but `hm` turns out to be null which I am guessing means the `.getParameterMap()` isn't finding the key/value pairs. Where am I going wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Have you had a look at what data and how the data is sent to the server? I don't think `myDataVar.toString()` is what you want.

Comment: I am concatinating the data into the string variable myDataVar so the data could be configured anyway I want. I have it this way because I did the same thing in another module which works fine. However, the data in that module is a bit different and I am using the default of JQuery .ajax type which I think is GET.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You don't want a string, you really want a JS map of key value pairs. E.g., change:

```
 data: myDataVar.toString(),
```

with:

```
var myKeyVals = { A1984 : 1, A9873 : 5, A1674 : 2, A8724 : 1, A3574 : 3, A1165 : 5 }



var saveData = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "someaction.do?action=saveData",
      data: myKeyVals,
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(resultData) { alert("Save Complete") }
});
saveData.error(function() { alert("Something went wrong"); });
```

jQuery understands key value pairs like that, it does NOT understand a big string. It passes it simply as a string.

**UPDATE:** Code fixed.

Comment: I think I tried that in one of my iteration attempts.  My question with this post is how to I get at the data on the server side?  The hashmap statements above don't do what I need them to do.

Comment: Even after a long time working with JSON and jQuery AJAX requests, I made the silly mistake today of writing my value for the "data" parameter as a string rather than an object. I didn't even realise I'd done it that way until I saw your answer. Goes to show you can miss problems that are staring you in the face. Thanks for jogging me straight.

Answer (score 14):

Simple method to sending data using java script and ajex call.

First right your form like this

```
<form id="frm_details" method="post" name="frm_details">
<input  id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email id" type="text" />
    <button class="subscribe-box__btn" type="submit">Need Assistance</button>
</form>
```

javascript logic  target on form id #frm_details after sumbit

```
$(function(){
        $("#frm_details").on("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var formData = {
                'email': $('input[name=email]').val() //for get email 
            };
            console.log(formData);

            $.ajax({
                url: "/tsmisc/api/subscribe-newsletter",
                type: "post",
                data: formData,
                success: function(d) {
                    alert(d);
                }
            });
        });
    }) 





General 
Request URL:https://test.abc
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:13.76.33.57:443

From Data
email:abc@invalid.ts
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use ajax post as :

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "url", 
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: JSON.stringify({ name: 'value1', email: 'value2' }),
   success: function (result) {
       // when call is sucessfull
    },
    error: function (err) {
    // check the err for error details
    }
 }); // ajax call closing
```

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I am going a different route than I previous stated.   I changed the way I am formatting the data to:

```
  &A2168=1&A1837=5&A8472=1&A1987=2
```

On the server side I am using getParameterNames() to place all the keys into an Enumerator and then iterating over the Enumerator and placing the keys and values into a HashMap.  It looks something like this:

```
Enumeration keys = request.getParameterNames(); 
HashMap map = new HashMap(); 
String key = null; 
while(keys.hasMoreElements()){ 
      key = keys.nextElement().toString(); 
      map.put(key, request.getParameter(key)); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the value from the servlet from `POST` command, you can follow the approach as explained on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293991/how-to-get-the-data-via-ajax-in-servlet/9299128#9299128) by using `request.getParameter(key)` format which will return the value you want.