# OnClick fopen fread fwrite fclose

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have a image:

```
 <img src="imagini/floo.gif" onclick="score()">
```

and i want "on click" to be opened a file "c.txt".
That file's content is:
0

And i want on every click, to be added 100 in c.txt.

I want something like this:

```
 <img src="imagini/floo.gif" onclick="score()">
<script> function score(){ (..do file add.php ...) }</script>
```

And add.php:

```
<?php
$c = "c.txt";
$fh = fopen($c, "r");
$current = fread($fh, filesize($c));
fclose($fh);
$current++;
$fh = fopen($c, "w");
fwrite($fh,$current);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

What to put in place: "(..do file add.php ...)" for the code to work?

Comment: Try using ajax and jQuery, and posting the data.  Them use the on click or (pseudo code) $`('#link').click.action{function` etc.  not very strong with jquery to run the function with Ajax inside

Comment: can you tell me all the code, please?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214723/jquery-ajax-post-data

Comment: what to take from there?

Answer (score 1):

You need to send an AJAX request to process the file. Here is a jQuery version of the code:

```
function score() {
    $.post("add.php", function(data) {
       //This callback executes after the request was successfull
       // echo something back to read from here as `data`
       console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: it must be like this: <script>function score() {
    $.post("add.php", function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    });
}</script> ?