# returning error response in jquery

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am trying to call a controller from jquery.Here every thing works fine,but in ajax it shows error alert. What is going wrong.

```
$.ajax({
                         type: 'POST',
                         url:'<%=request.getContextPath()%>/billing',
                         data: ({caseId: caseId,  noteID :  noteID}),    
                         cache: false,
                         success: function(data){
                                alert("Success");
                            },
                         error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
                         alert("Error occured.");
                         }
                         });
```

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/billing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String Billing(@RequestParam Long caseId,
            @RequestParam Long noteID, HttpServletRequest request)  throws Exception {
        try{

           ----Some data base updation---
            logger.debug("success ");
        return "success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e,e);
            throw e;
        }}
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: Try checking the _textStatus,error_ params in error callback , those will give you a little more info.Also i would recommend checking the server logs too .

Comment: while passing the data you really don't need round bracket in `data: ({caseId: caseId,  noteID :  noteID})`. Please remove them (starting `(` and ending `)`)and you will not get any error.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10215019/5934435)

Answer (score 0):

//you have to left content type to send the server side ,please define content type..

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("PerTGradeMastEdit", "Master")',
                data: "{'Request':'" + request + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response != null) {

                        var strResponse = response;
                        var ProgramData = strResponse.split("/");
                        // response = ProgramData[0];programId
                        $('#txtPerGrade').val(ProgramData[0]);
                        $('#txtDesc').val(ProgramData[1]);

                    }
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("INDEX", "AUTHORIZE")';
                }
            });`enter code here`
```