# How to submit checkbox through jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have difficulty submitting this form:

```
<form action="/someurl" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="7mLw36HxPTlt4gapxLUKWOpe1GsqA0I5"> 
    <input type="checkbox" class="mychoice" name="name" value="apple"> Apple
    <input type="checkbox" class="mychoice" name="name" value="orange"> Orange      
    <input type="checkbox" class="mychoice" name="name" value="pear"> Pear
  </form>
```

And the jquery bit:

```
$('.mychoice').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/someurl',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
                 //  ... do something with the data...
                 }
    });
});
```

But nothing happens when I click a checkbox. How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:** It may worth mentioning that the form is located at a bootstrap modal.

Comment: When are you running the jquery code?

Comment: It is supposed to run on a bootstrap modal.

Comment: Are you sure that your elements are in the DOM when your code runs? Can you post a snippet example?

Comment: you need to include the data attribute in your ajax syntax.  Also, I don't see where your attempting to get the actual value of the check box.  I think this will help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834350/get-checkbox-value-in-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the `data` property.

See: [JQuery $.ajax() post - data in a java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214723/jquery-ajax-post-data) for an example.

If you want to send the contents of the form, then you would use `Form.serialize()`, but you could put whatever data you want into the property.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mychoice').click(function() {
    var formData = $('#myForm').serialize();
    console.log('Posting the following: ', formData);
    
    $.ajax({
      url: '/someurl',
      data: formData,
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        //  ... do something with the data...
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/someurl" method="post" id="myForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="7mLw36HxPTlt4gapxLUKWOpe1GsqA0I5">
  <input type="checkbox" class="mychoice" name="name" value="apple">Apple
  <input type="checkbox" class="mychoice" name="name" value="orange">Orange
  <input type="checkbox" class="mychoice" name="name" value="pear">Pear
</form>
```

Comment: data is only required for sending post requests, else any data can be added to the url itself.

Comment: What does `type: 'post'` mean? Is it something different to you?

Comment: i didn't downvote you so keep your pants on. even still you didnt explain how to serialize the form or populate the data so it's still only half an answer.

Comment: I didn't explain how to serialize the form or populate the data because Karlom didn't specify what data that endpoint should receive. And my pants are still on, but only because I'm at work. :)

Comment: Well, I added `data: $('#myForm').serialize(),` but still does not work. Could it be because the form is on a bootstrap modal?

Comment: Did you add `id="myForm"` to the form element? A Boostrap modal should still be accessible in the DOM.

Comment: Yes I did add `id="myForm"` to the form.

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that. Is the dialog content in a different frame?

Comment: No, I don't use frames. I just have the form on a bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mychoice').change( function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/someurl',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                //  ... do something with the data...
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Mister Positive In what way does it not answer the question. He asked what he can do; I said try this. That sounds like an answer to me, but then again, I've only spoken English my whole life.

Answer (score 0):

supply missing data

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mychoice').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/someurl',
      data: $(this).closest('form').serialize(),
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        //  ... do something with the data...
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to receive the data with the csrf token  do as below :

```
var fd = new FormData()
fd.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value)
fd.append('field_name', $("input[name='field_name']").serialize())
```

will return

```
['field_name=9&field_name=15&field_name=10']
```

you will then have to parse the info in your view ( django )

Answer (score -1):

Try 'change' instead of 'click', like this:

```
$('.mychoice').change(function(){...})
```

Comment: I did, but has no effect. I even added a `alert("clicked")` inside the jquery function, but it is not triggered when I tick a checkbox.

Comment: @Karlom in Chrome right-click then select "inspect element", you probably have javascript error which causes javascript to stop, OR, jquery is not included correctly