# Spring controller gives bad request 400

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

I often pass JSON to my spring controllers as part of the request body.  Not for the life of me, I cannot get this one to work? Give me 400 bad request.

Spring controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/saverefunds", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String saveRefunds(Model model, HttpSession session, AS400WriteRefundLine as400WriteRefundLine, @RequestBody CreateRefund refunddetails) throws ParseException, IOException {
////
}
```

Javascript code which makes a call to it:

```
let refunddetails = {
            blackbookno: refundedInvoiceNo,
            RfExno: "00",                                      
            transactionType: "R",
            stockid: stockid,
            sku: sku,
            refundtype: refundtype,
            refundreason: refundreason,
            btsflag: btsflag,
            uniqueid: uniqueid,
            thisrefundamount: thisrefund,
            firstrecord: firstRecord.toString(),                
            nextRfEx:"1",                                        
            firstname: wFname,
            surname: wLname,
            address1: wAdd1,
            address2: wAdd2,
            town: wTown,
            county: wCounty,
            landline: wTelno,
            mobile: wMobile,
            email: wEmail
        };

        await $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: "saverefunds",
            data: JSON.stringify(refunddetails),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                if (data.substring(0, 2) != "OK:") {
                    // ERROR
                    alert("postErr: " + data);
                } else {
                    alert('Refund Generated');
                }
                return true;
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('ERROR:'+error.responseText);
            }
        });
```

The CreateRefund object:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class CreateRefund {
    private String blackbookno, RfExno, transactionType, stockid, sku, refundtype, refundreason, btsflag,
            uniqueid, thisrefundamount, firstrecord, nextRfEx, firstname,
            surname, address1, address2, town, county, landline, mobile, email;
}
```

The POJO matches the JSON being passed so not sure what else it could be?

Anybody see anything obviously wrong?

The only way I can pass the data across is by using Map<String,String> in the spring controller as opposed to CreateRefund object...So I'm assuming the json mapping isn't working?

Many thanks

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: try this: `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` and report what happens. The default setting is `false` if not explicitly declared.

Comment: Many thanks @RandyCasburn - this as sorted it!  This is the answer!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted and happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you convert your data to string before sending.

```
  await $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: "saverefunds",
            data: refunddetails,  <---------pass the json object here
            success: function (data) {
```

Also

```
public String saveRefunds(Model model, HttpSession session, AS400WriteRefundLine as400WriteRefundLine, @RequestBody CreateRefund refunddetails) throws ParseException, IOException {
////
```

What exactly is `AS400WriteRefundLine as400WriteRefundLine` and how will spring know what value to put there?

Comment: This is not so. jQuery will accept a string as the data parameter and simply pass that along as the body of the POST request. "_When data is passed as a string it should already be encoded using the correct encoding for contentType_" from here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ - in this case the contentType matches the JSON encoding.

Comment: A similar issue was already solved here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10215019/7237884 I am pretty sure that this is the issue, in reality I had the same issue in the past

Comment: `.toString()` does not produce JSON - it is _not_ the same issue.