# how to convert to json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This could be a basic question but , i'm stuck with this for some time.

i have a data

```
{pid: 'WEB506', session: 'WEB506_09092021_M1_S1.csv'}
```

how to convert this to

```
{
        "pid":"WEB506",
        "session":"WEB506_09092021_M1_S2.csv"
        };
```

regards. i used JSON.stringify and i got it as

```
{"pid":"WEB506","session":"WEB506_09092021_M1_S1.csv"}
```

but when i pass this to ajax data to call an api , the value entering req.body is

```
{ '{"pid":"WEB506","session":"WEB506_09092021_M1_S1.csv"}': '' }
```

This is my ajax call

```
function graphApi(){
    
     const apiValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
     
   console.log(apiValue,"apiValue");
      const f = JSON.stringify(apiValue);
      console.log(f,"ffff")
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:  f,   
       
        url: "http://localhost:5000/File",
        success: function (data) { 
        console.log(data,"graph api");
         }
```

I really don't know what is happening.

regards

Comment: How are you passing the ajax data? Did you try passing the object as-is?

Comment: passing the data as a string.

Comment: provide code for ajax code

Comment: @ Ravi Ashara please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69565573/my-ajax-call-return-object-object-and-api-is-unsucess

Comment: Please include all relevant information in this question. [Edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69795015/edit) to add details

Comment: @fungusblacky check this link 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214723/jquery-ajax-post-data-in-a-java-servlet'

Comment: [@fungusblacky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15329278/fungusblacky) I face this I thing you are not getting JSON right? you want to dig out JSON

Comment: yes @SmitGajera

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify()`

should give you serialized string for your data.

I think the issue here is you are passing the string as the payload to the AJAX call whereas you should use the data(i.e the object) directly in `req. body`.
See if this helps

Comment: i did this but  no hope

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify() is used to stringify the objects

Answer (score 0):

This is your Object Right

```
   const object = {
                  "pid":"WEB506",
                  "session":"WEB506_09092021_M1_S2.csv"
                };
```

Now Pass this object in the below method

```
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(object);
console.log(jsonObject)
```

Now you can dig out your PID or SESSIONS with

```
const pid = jsonObject.pid
const session = jsonObject.session
```

Comment: If you are getting this object from the body you can directly parse it from `JSON.parse(req.body)`

Comment: bro what i have is  this {pid: 'WEB506', session: 'WEB506_09092021_M1_S1.csv'} , which i got as {"pid":"WEB506","session":"WEB506_09092021_M1_S1.csv"} when i use JSON.stringify. and i pass this stringified data to ajax , which gives  { '{"pid":"WEB506","session":"WEB506_09092021_M1_S1.csv"}': '' }  in my req.body in api